# Focus on input field when popup shown(bootstrap popover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have html body with this button:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="image-copy-to-clipboard image-copy-to-clipboard-icon" role="button" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body">
    <div class="head hide">Press Ctrl+C to copy user info</div>
    <div class="content hide">
        <input id="userInfo" type="text" placeholder="" value="#{{user.Id}} : {{user.Name}}" autofocus="autofocus" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And this script to make it works:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
});

$('#userInfo').focus(function (event) {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
         self.select();
    }, 100);
});

$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'HTML') {
        $('.popover.fade').hide().remove();
    }
});
```

When popup window shown I need to focus on input field and all text must be selected. I tried a lot of issues but nothing works normally. Please help me solve this problem.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/b991st3m/1/)

Comment: Thanks to all, the result is https://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/e9yqyas1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the trigger function jazZRo provided and got it working like so:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
     $('.popover').find("#userInfo").focus().select();
});
```

Have a look at the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e9yqyas1/)

Also note that I removed the  `data-trigger="focus"` from the HTML code and let your JQuery code close the *popover* when the document is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed my problem!:)

Comment: @HUSTLIN Check multiple browsers before you use this. IE has difficulties for example.

Answer (score 0):

Useing Bootstrap Popup window :

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the `shown.bs.popover` event to fire. It will fire when the popover has opened:

Replace:

```
$('#userInfo').focus(function (event) { 
    ...
```

With:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({...}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
     $('#userInfo').focus();
});
```

EDIT: The problem this still didn't work was because of the dynamically inserted content. [See this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b991st3m/8/).

I chained the methods because the event needs to be on the same jQuery object. Also to get this working the popover needs to be triggered manually, otherwise the popover immediately closes after the focus.